# I keep getting UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR while uploading file using PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache, server, fedora-25

I am trying to upload a file on my Apache server on Fedora 25 (32 bit) using PHP 7.0.15.

I am getting an **UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR error**, even though I have set appropriate (and even more than I should have, but I am working locally at the moment) permissions for the upload directories and i have changed the owner of the directory to apache.

I am trying to upload a .docx file 6kB large, my `upload_tmp_dir` in `php.ini` is set to `/home/temporary`.

`ls -l` returns the following code:

```
drwxrwxrwx.  2 apache root           4096 Feb 11 20:14 temporary
```

`sys_get_tmp_dir()` returns the correct path: `/home/temporary`

But I still get error 6

```
debug outputArray
(
[userfile] => Array
    (
        [name] => rus.docx
        [type] => 
        [tmp_name] => 
        [error] => 6
        [size] => 0
    )
)
```

What can cause this problem?

Comment: does php accept your upload_tmp_dir ? Check the right value in phpinfo() in runtime?

Comment: @Roman Yes, the path is correct there, so probably the problem is somewhere in the permissions

Comment: try changing tmp dir in php.ini

Comment: It's very likely that SELinux (or the tool your distro has) does not allow access to home directories (which are private by concept) from services that are open to the world (such as http).

Comment: What do you get if you run `ls -halZ /home/temporary`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the temporary directory under `/var/www` or `/var/www/html`.

Apart from this action you also need to grant `Apache` the `rewrite` permissions with semanage.

Comment: This is a very old post, but since this is the accepted answer, I think it might be better to clear this up: I don't think it is a good idea to put the temp folder inside the htdocs, since it should not be accessible to the browser.  The important thing is that Apache needs to be able to write to the directory.  You may want to use something like /var/tmp or similar.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check few things in your `php.ini`. Make sure you are hitting right `php.ini`:

- `upload_tmp_dir`: This is the directory where PHP stores temporary files while uploading.
- `open_basedir`: Limits PHP read/write rights operation to a specified path and its subdirectories. **Make sure upload_tmp_dir is inside this path!**
- `post_max_size`: Make it bigger to accommodate your uploaded size.
- `upload_max_filesize`: Allowed limit of file size.

If you want to tweak with tmp directory setting try editing `/etc/profile` or /`etc/environment` of your choice (for current session only or for all time) and above checks works with it.