# Problems when uploading image to server nginx php 7.4 UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR with same req

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config, php-7.4

I'm trying to upload an image with postman to my server. The problem is that it sometimes works and sometimes it does not.

I'm using exactly the same request every time. Is this some kind of protection within nginx or php?

When it works:

```
 [image] => Array
        (
            [name] => 9.jpeg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /home/test/tmp/php9LDwAL
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 351162
        )
```

When it fails:

```
[image] => Array
        (
            [name] => 9.jpeg
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 6
            [size] => 0
        )
```

PHP 7.4.29

edit 1: found some error logs:

```
File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/test/web/site.com/public_html:
/home/test/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
```

```
[Fri May 20 19:56:02.661312 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 15995] PHP Warning:  
File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0
```

edit 2:

I think i found the problem.
When uploading a file to the server it uses sometimes
**sys_temp_dir** and sometimes **upload_tmp_dir** as upload_dir

i first changed sys_temp_dir to **/home/test/tmp** without luck. After changing it to **/home/test/web/site.com/public_html/tmp/** it is now working, but still does not feel like a proper solution.

Can someone please explain why the upload occasionally uses different paths? **sys_temp_dir** / **upload_tmp_dir**

Comment: Please don't tag apache on questions about nginx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42393026/5962802